# How do I initialize =SUM field in JavaScript SpreadSheet

Tags: javascript, sum, spreadsheet

I am creating a spreadsheet using JavaScript and cannot figure out how to valuate the `=SUM` field. My code will produce an array ex `(=SUM,A1,B1)` but I am lost on how to change the attribute of A1 and B1 to grab the value of their associated fields.

```
function saveCell()
{
// get the text the user just typed into the text box
var cellText = document.getElementById("txtCell").value;

var tokenArray = getFormula(cellText);

// if null... this isn't a formula
if (tokenArray != null)
{
    alert("This is a formula to sum from " + tokenArray[1] + " to " + tokenArray[2]);

}
else
    currentRef.innerHTML = cellText;

    ssArray[currentRow - 1][currentCol - 1] = cellText;
}//end saveCell()


// determines if user entered a formula such as =SUM(A1:B1)
// returns an array with cell coordinates

function getFormula(tbValue)
{

// this is a regular expression pattern which is intended to
// split the string (formula) on any of ":" "(" or ")"
var pattern = /[:|\(|\)]/;

// do the split ... ar is an array
var ar = tbValue.split(pattern);

// convert =sum to upper case
var sum = ar[0].toUpperCase();
var attOne = ar[1];
var attTwo = ar[2];

if (ar.length < 3)
    return null;
else if (sum != "=SUM")
    return alert("The function '"+sum+"' is not supported...");
else
{
    //return an array of strings
    return ar;
    }
}//end getFormula()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm If I understand well, A1, and B1 should be de "id" of the elements in where the values are stored, so you should get inside those elements and obtain the values.

In such case, you can use `document.getelementbyid(attOne).value` to obtain the value inside the A1 field;

Although I'm a bit lost by your question, may be you should post the structure of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the value stored in A1 and B1 but as they are stored into an array i need to split A from 1 and B from 1 to be able to use them to access row[1]col[A].
Also, I am using VisualStudio and semi new to JavaScript. I don't understand were you are getting "dom." from.

Comment: I see, well the Document Object Model (DOM) is an application programming interface (API) for valid HTML and well-formed XML documents. You can read full info about DOM here [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)

Comment: I just realized that I had an error, instead of writting document, I wrote dom, sorry about that.

Comment: i figured so, no worries.
The document.getelementbyid() will not work with this though because i need to first split the A from the 1 and access the array values... I might have forgot to mention I have completely created the spreadsheet from new, so I have stored all my fields into an array. The A and 1 will be used to access row[1]col[A] so A1 does not have a value as of yet. I can send you my entire VS file if that might help?

Comment: When programing with javascript you should change a bit your mind, first you can add an id atribute to every field, use that id (that can be A1B1) to access the A1B1 field.